# Vacation approval request?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, permissions

Is it possible to create workflow when your manager approves your vacation in Vacation Request list than In Calender list it creates new item??

How i can do that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.
You can simply setup a workflow to create a new item in the calendar list, depending on the approval decision on the Vacation list.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

- Assign the specified supervisor a task to review and approve or
  reject the request.
- If approved, send an email to HR with the details of the request
- Send the person that submitted the request a confirmation message
- Add the name and dates to a departmental vacation calendar
- If rejected, send the requestor a message with supervisor comments

check this blog for detailed steps, which use the SPD to create a workflow.

http://everydaytechstuff.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/creating-a-vacation-request-workflow-in-sharepoint-designer/